# Parsing php code conditionally to avoid parse errors on older php versions

Tags: php

I have scripts that must be run with PHP 5.1.0 or higher (because using PDO class, for instance).
If not, they bring parse errors.

I'm talking of scripts that anonymous visitors are invited to download, install on their server (on which I can't have any information) and run to demonstrate how easy php scripts can communicate with a system of ours.

Of course, running any of these scripts and getting a *"parse error at line xxx"* won't really give a good image of the solution...

I tried echoing a neat *"you need PHP 5.1.0 or higher to run this script"* error message, using `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0') < 0) { die(...); }` but, of course, this doesn't work, as PHP ***first*** parses the whole script ***before*** starting executing it and having a chance to die on this test.

So my question is:
**Is there a way in PHP to do some tests on php version BEFORE actually parsing?**
I mean something like C/C++ `#if` or `#ifdef` PRE-processor directives.
Or any other type of workaround?

One constraint beeing: the solution to the issue should not make the whole scripts look unreadable or complex to understand (like massive calling of `eval()` which breaks syntax coloration) nor uncomprehensibly contrived (like having each script conditionaly included in a "container script"), because the global purpose is to demonstrate how SIMPLE it is to communicate with our system...
All solutions found googling around were about maintaining compatibility, using arrays of alternative functions to call depending on php version, comined with eval everywhere where something could go wrong for php parser... I would need something really simpler like "if php version not ok, don't parse"...

Comment: How about also having an `else { require 'actual_code_requiring_5.1.0.php'; }` after the `if(version_compare...`?

Comment: As above. Two files is not `"uncomprehensibly contrived"` and works nicely

Comment: This could be achieved in some frameworks and concepts with a bootstrapper. All requests go through the bootstrapper, which can check the PHP version before processing the request. This is what @SergiuParaschiv is explaining as well.

Comment: This was one of my first thoughts but this would mean, for each of the 20 small scripts of the demo, having a script just doing "test version and either die or include actual script". Doubling the number of scripts isn't compliant to the image of simplicity we want to give... This is what I called "uncomprehensibly contrived" for the visitors trying to test the product, see last point "constraint" of my question.

Comment: If you are going for more user friendliness I'd go as far as to have a form where the user enters the domain this script is going to run and makes a GET request to it. Default PHP configuration adds a `X-Powered-By` header that contains the PHP version.

Comment: `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') < 0) { echo("You are using an older, unsupported version of PHP. Please upgrade to the most recent version"; }` :-)

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv This sounds good, I'll have a try in this direction. Apparently for the first comments, seems to confirm there's nothing like preprocessing directives in php, it's not just me not finding them in the doc...

Comment: `"for each of the 20 small scripts of the demo"` Make access for all the demos go through one file, eg demos.php. This file contains the check, and if passed includes a second php file (say demolist.php) that just has an html list of links to the actual demos.

Comment: Just an idea: write a simple install script that checks the PHP version then, if it is recent enough for your small samples, download the sample from your website using `cUrl`, saves it locally and displays the path where it was saved. Or, if it runs in the browser then displays its content in an iframe etc. Let the visitors download a customized version of the install script that contains the name/URL of the actual script hardcoded in its first lines.

Comment: @axiac first comment: I see no difference to what I explained was not working, see my question, besides your change in the version... This doesnt prevent php to parse and throw parse errors on the code following this condition.

Comment: @axiac 2: this is what I actually do (check version, check base identifiers, creates tables using non PDO lib only if version is ok for future use of other scripts...), but if the user calls other scripts than the install one, I would have prefered smthg nicer than "parse error"...

Comment: The "install script" idea sounds good to me too. Have a simple install.php script that (1) checks if it's not already installed and (2) checks the version. If everything passes then it downloads the actual demo scripts.

Comment: @fpierrat That comment was off-topic, indeed. The point was that version 5.1 is very outdated. If your visitors use older versions of PHP maybe it's not your concern to make the scripts run on their machines.

Comment: Though this would create major headaches with file permissions and having curl enabled or at least being able to run `wget`...

Comment: Indeed. I think the best solution is to clearly specify for each script in the downloads page what are the requirements: minimum PHP version, extensions etc. Since your audience is PHP developers they should know how to meet these requirements or to circumvent them in order to make your scripts work.

Comment: Another idea, that works well only with scripts that do not require access to external resources (database, file system etc): use an online PHP interpreter (search on Google, pick your favorite), put the script in it and add the link it provides to you into your download page with some explanatory text along the lines: "If your PHP is too old and the script doesn't compile, you can try it online here \[link to online version\]". Sure, this doesn't solve your problem but it can provide an alternative solution for users that runs old PHP versions. It even allows them to run the code :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll stay on my "install.php" checking version, and make clear on the download page in big fat red characters: "beware, php xxx or higher required" + same comment in the header of each script. And if users launch another script on an old system, maybe I can't help. I thought there would be some nice'n easy trick I had overseen :-(